# Visual Studio 2010. Is there a way to export all Settings as well as Macros and Plugins?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, export

I've got VS2010 and I need to wipe my HDD and start over.  I know I can export my settings which is nice, but what about my plugins and such? Do I need to gather them all up and reinstall them, or is there a way to export them all in one go?

- GhostDoc
- Comment Reflower
- JS Extensions
- Custom Macros
- Etc

Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends entirely on the add-in in question as to how it will be installed, so it's unlikely that you'll find a one-stop solution that will solve the re-install.

Even if a tool was available to do this (which I doubt) I'd personally do the install manually anyway so that I know everything is as "clean" as possible. (After all, the 10 minutes it'll take to do your add-ins is nothing compared to the time it'll take for the OS and VS2010 installs)

(You could always save a bit of time with my [AtomineerUtils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) add-in - It installs in about 2 seconds, and has very similar features to both Comment Reflower and GhostDoc)